# Double entries in sqlite_sequence table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

In our Sqlite database there is `sqlite_sequence` table that has double entries with different seq IDs.

For example

```
NAME            SEQ
MyTableName1    1280
MyTableName1    3000
```

When and how are those entries created? I suppose they are making certain problems within  application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How did this happen?

Either

- (1) the 2nd row has been inserted outside of SQLite's hanlding,

or perhaps

- (2) it is the end result of a transaction that has not been committed i.e. where `setTransactionSuccessful()` has not been invoked, when 1720 rows have been inserted.

  - Note this would appear to contradict :-
  - > **There is a single row** in the sqlite_sequence table for each ordinary
    >   table that uses AUTOINCREMENT. The name of the table (as it appears in
    >   sqlite_master.name) is in the sqlite_sequence.main field and the
    >   largest INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ever inserted into that table is in the
    >   sqlite_sequence.seq field. [2.6.2. The sqlite_sequence table](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab)

However, I've not tested this latter scenario. My thought is that when a transaction includes inserts for an AUTOINCREMENT column then SQLite needs to keep track of the pending rowid's and thus could utilise a separate row for this purpose.

---

> I suppose they are making certain problems within application.

I would assume not. As from some limited testing the first row according to rowid is used so 1280 will be considered as the highest sequence number.
[How is rowid determined on sqlite insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933148/how-is-rowid-determined-on-sqlite-insertion/47935521#47935521)

So if the former (the 3000 row was inserted outside of SQLite's management), then **1281** (or greater) would be the next value used for the `AUTOINCREMENT` column. So the **3000** value would effectively be ignored.

If the latter (transaction not committed) then as the transaction wasn't committed, the correct highest sequence would be **1280**, (*1281 or higher will be the next*) and the **3000** would be ignored, so again no negative impact.

If for some reason there were a higher sequence value let's say 6000 used by the AUTOINCREMENT column, then from limited testing, that would be considered as the highest value and 6001 would be the next (see testing undertaken in the link previously given).

In short the next sequence would appear (according to limited testing as per the link) to be the higher of the highest used value in the `AUTOINCREMENT` column (same as for without `AUTOINCREMENT`) or the value that is obtained from the first row (according to rowid in ascending order) from the respective name in the **sqlite_sequence** table.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a valid answer and explains whats going on. I'll mark it as answered.